# Unable to install protobuf in https://colab.research.google.com

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to install `apt-get install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml` in  https://colab.research.google.com:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libprotobuf10 libprotoc10
  libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpmux3 libxslt1.1 python-bs4 python-chardet
  python-html5lib python-olefile python-six python-webencodings
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils python-genshi python-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc python-pil-doc
  python-pil-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 liblcms2-2 libprotobuf10 libprotoc10
  libtiff5 libwebp6 libwebpmux3 libxslt1.1 protobuf-compiler python-bs4
  python-chardet python-html5lib python-lxml python-olefile python-pil
  python-six python-webencodings
0 upgraded, 19 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 3,734 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

But I am unable to continue by saying `Y`.

Comment: What if you just press enter?

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Colab now supports input prompts, so you should see confirmations and can answer as needed like so.

[image]

**Old answer:** Try invoking `apt-get` with the `-y` argument, which will accept all confirmation prompts.

For example:

`apt-get -y install protobuf-compiler python-pil python-lxml`

Example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1I6F8Oum_l7QAfUhH6Aj3zUYtnO3rly14